# encrypted ZFS disk failure

Tags: linux, encryption, zfs

If I [encrypt](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54801/gkkih.html) a ZFS disk that is in mirrored or in RAID-Z (raidz, raidz1, raidz2, raidz3) configurations then what happens if a disk fails. Can I still access the data if I replace a HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer this with specific regard to Linux, but assuming you're talking about either full-disk or full-partition encryption, my experience with ZFS on FreeBSD suggests that it won't matter.

As long as ZFS can import the pool, you'll be able to remove a failed drive, provision a new drive with or without full-(drive|partition) encryption, and resilver the existing functional devices (encrypted or not) onto the newly-provisioned device (encrypted or not).

All that matters is that the redundancy of the pool is sufficient that you can do a `zpool import -N` and successfully import the (degraded) pool so that you can remove and replace the failed device.

```
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 01:51:20 with 0 errors on Mon Jul 26 05:11:07 2021
config:

    NAME            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank            ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada1p3.eli  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada0p3      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Here device `/dev/ada0p3` is an unencrypted partition, while `ada1p3` is an encrypted partition (and ada1p3.eli is the **de**crypted handle for it).

There's no real reason for this setup on my machine, it's just the end result of when I was futzing around playing with booting from a full-disk encrypted pool.